# Excel: Count Unique Dates for set of multiple criteria

Tags: excel

I have a large spreadsheet with many data columns and dates .  Column B is the date column and there are multiple rows of duplicate dates with different data in the following columns.   I'm trying to write a formula to give me a count of how many unique dates there were given different criteria.  I did this formula entered as an array and it worked perfectly.

```
=COUNT(1/FREQUENCY(IF(('NA Trades'!D:D="TSX D3")*('NA Trades'!DX:DX>16),IF('NA Trades'!B:B<>"",'NA Trades'!B:B)),IF(('NA Trades'!D:D="TSX D3")*('NA Trades'!DX:DX>16),IF('NA Trades'!B:B<>"",'NA Trades'!B:B))))
```

I tried expanding on this and adding more criteria but it doesn't seem to be working and giving me a result of 0.  This is the array formula I tried with the added criteria

```
'=COUNT(1/FREQUENCY(IF(('NA Trades'!D:D="TSX D3")*('NA Trades'!DX:DX>16)*('NA Trades'!DQ:DQ<-2.6),IF('NA Trades'!B:B<>"",'NA Trades'!B:B)),IF(('NA Trades'!D:D="TSX D3")*('NA Trades'!DX:DX>16)*('NA Trades'!DQ:DQ<-2.6),IF('NA Trades'!B:B<>"",'NA Trades'!B:B))))
```

Where did I go wrong with the second formula and how can I format this formula so I can continue to add more criteria?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your formula seems to be working fine, are you sure you have the correct data in your newly added column?  BTW, I would suggest that you use named ranges or a table - it's easier to read.

Comment: Thank you, I think I had an error in the data that's causing my issue!